# Graph network visualisation in flutter?

Tags: flutter, plot, dart, visualization

I'm a newbie in flutter. Would anybody have an idea of how to plot a graph network in flutter?

An example using d3js is below. I'm interested in a solution that doesn't use d3js so it could work on mobiles.

Thank you

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/graph_collection

Comment: Thank you but this package doesn't contain a way to display and interact with the graph, like moving nodes.

Comment: I seen you have post since 3 months, now do you have any solution yet?

Comment: No I don't have any.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

This package seems to be an answer (very basic compared to d3 though):
https://pub.dev/packages/graphview

Also I noticed this answer today:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59840394/884752

The package seems more advanced.