# Flutter directed graph. Can I use CustomPainter Class with custom widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-canvas

I want to build a directed graph like in the picture below with flutter. 
I dont know where to start. I searched at internet without success. Which algorihms do I need for this kind of graph?
I tried to build this graph with custom painter class. I dont know how to use custom widgets inside custom painter class. (for example a rect with a picture of person and text beside).
I only was able to draw rect and lines...
Zoom and pan I thought I can do with GestureDetector class.
The graph should be customizable dynamicly.

[image]

Comment: what is your logic for relation between nodes?

Comment: Can you post the code you wrote using custom painter class which you mentioned as you already tried..! Also the logic behind how the nodes should be placed in the graph. Otherwise the question seems too broad and looks like asking for a working implementation all together. In my humble opinion this is definitely achievable using custom painter in flutter.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to split your tasks.

1. Make the layer to zoom and move whole scene, you can use the
   GestureDetector widget with onScale events + Transform.scale widget,
   (check zoom_widget package).
2. Make the single item draggable. Use GestureDetector + onPan events.
3. Draw connection lines between element using CustomPainter. I've made direct lines to show the main logic.

.. add extra logic how to add new items.

**Update:**
[codepen interactive version](http://codepen.io/maks-the-lessful/pen/OJMLZav) created by @maks

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: ItemsScene(),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ItemsScene extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ItemsSceneState createState() => _ItemsSceneState();
}

class _ItemsSceneState extends State<ItemsScene> {
  List<ItemModel> items = [
    ItemModel(offset: Offset(70, 100), text: 'text1'),
    ItemModel(offset: Offset(200, 100), text: 'text2'),
    ItemModel(offset: Offset(200, 230), text: 'text3'),
  ];

  Function onDragStart(int index) => (x, y) {
        setState(() {
          items[index] = items[index].copyWithNewOffset(Offset(x, y));
        });
      };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        CustomPaint(
          size: Size(double.infinity, double.infinity),
          painter: CurvedPainter(
            offsets: items.map((item) => item.offset).toList(),
          ),
        ),
        ..._buildItems()
      ],
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _buildItems() {
    final res = <Widget>[];
    items.asMap().forEach((ind, item) {
      res.add(_Item(
        onDragStart: onDragStart(ind),
        offset: item.offset,
        text: item.text,
      ));
    });

    return res;
  }
}

class _Item extends StatelessWidget {
  _Item({
    Key key,
    this.offset,
    this.onDragStart,
    this.text,
  });

  final double size = 100;
  final Offset offset;
  final Function onDragStart;
  final String text;

  _handleDrag(details) {
    print(details);
    var x = details.globalPosition.dx;
    var y = details.globalPosition.dy;
    onDragStart(x, y);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      left: offset.dx - size / 2,
      top: offset.dy - size / 2,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onPanStart: _handleDrag,
        onPanUpdate: _handleDrag,
        child: Container(
          width: size,
          height: size,
          child: Text(text),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CurvedPainter extends CustomPainter {
  CurvedPainter({this.offsets});

  final List<Offset> offsets;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    if (offsets.length > 1) {
      offsets.asMap().forEach((index, offset) {
        if (index == 0) return;
        canvas.drawLine(
          offsets[index - 1],
          offsets[index],
          Paint()
            ..color = Colors.red
            ..strokeWidth = 2,
        );
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CurvedPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}

class ItemModel {
  ItemModel({this.offset, this.text});

  final Offset offset;
  final String text;

  ItemModel copyWithNewOffset(Offset offset) {
    return ItemModel(offset: offset, text: text);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the **excellent** example code! I made a codepen out of it in case anyone wants to have an interactive version to try out: https://codepen.io/maks-the-lessful/pen/OJMLZav

Comment: @Kherel wooooooooow, thats very awesome, thanks my dude

Answer (score 0):

CustomPainter seems like overkill. Use Stack. You need to first calculate position and size of each node or connection and then place them using Positioned widgets.

Comment: yes, I have managed to make it, without using CustomPainter. i'am using Container as line between two dot.